# Sort array of structs by a member of each

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, struct

I am compiling data using the following structs:

```
struct Nursing {

var leftTime: Double
var rightTime: Double
var submissionTime: Date

}

struct Bottle {

var bottleQuantity: Double
var bottleUnits: String
var submissionTime: Date

}

struct Puree {

var pureeQuantity: Double
var pureeType: String
var pureeUnits: String
var submissionTime: Date

}
```

Then I create arrays of each type using data from elsewhere in the app.

```
var nursingArray = [Nursing]()
var bottleArray = [Bottle]()
var pureeArray = [Puree]()
```

I then filter each array for only entries that occurred in the last day.

```
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
    var todayBottleArray = bottleArray.filter( { ( $0.submissionTime > yesterday! ) } )
    var todayNursingArray = nursingArray.filter( { ( $0.submissionTime > yesterday! ) } )
    var todayPureeArray = pureeArray.filter( { ( $0.submissionTime > yesterday! ) } )
```

Finally they all get combined into a single unsorted array.

```
    var unsortedTodayArray: [Any] = []

    unsortedTodayArray.append(todayBottleArray)
    unsortedTodayArray.append(todayNursingArray)
    unsortedTodayArray.append(todayPureeArray)
```

Here's the question...while I know they're unrelated, the `submissionTime` property appears in all three.  How can I sort `unsortedTodayArray` by `submissionTime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have your struct conform to the same protocol. Something like...

```
protocol SubmissionTimeable {
    var submissionTime: Date { get set }
}

struct Nursing: SubmissionTimeable {

    var leftTime: Double
    var rightTime: Double
    var submissionTime: Date
}

struct Bottle: SubmissionTimeable {

    var bottleQuantity: Double
    var bottleUnits: String
    var submissionTime: Date
}

struct Puree: SubmissionTimeable {

    var pureeQuantity: Double
    var pureeType: String
    var pureeUnits: String
    var submissionTime: Date
}
```

Then let your unsorted array be an array of the protocol.

```
let unsortedArray = [SubmissionTimeable]()
```

Then you can sort that array with submissionTime.